# Weird spacing with whitespace newline mark "↴"

Tags: fonts, whitespace, newlines

I have my whitespace newline mark set to the "↴" character,

```
(setq whitespace-display-mappings '(
                                    (newline-mark 10 [8628 10])
                                    ))
```

Now, the spacing is fine when I use DejaVu monospace font, but with all the other fonts I've tried, I get this kind of behavior:
[image: weird spacing]

I know it's just because I'm using a weird whitespace character but I like it and I'd like to keep it. Is it just because of the font limitation, or are there other ways around this?

Thanks! :)

Comment: You will need to adjust the `:height` of the face `whitespace-newline` to essentially shrink the character until its size is less than or equal to the normal line height of the `'default` face.  This is a useful question, so perhaps try and think of a way to rewrite it to inquire about reducing the size of unicode characters that are displayed via the `buffer-display-table` -- otherwise, it may be considered a duplicate or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When newline character(s) is/are anything other than `\n`, the function `whitespace-display-char-on` creates a glyph code for the newline character(s) using the face named `whitespace-newline`, and that glyph code is then set as part of the `buffer-display-table` in lieu of `\n` or in addition to `\n`.

A workaround to the problem described by the original poster is to set the `:height` of the face `whitespace-newline` so that the chosen unicode character(s) is/are shrunken to a size that is less than or equal to the `'default` face `:height`.  This is a workaround, so the original poster will need to experiment to find the right number for the `:height` that suits his/her needs.  The disadvantage with this workaround is that the chosen unicode character(s) may be too small and not visually appealing.

The other solution, of course, is to select a unicode character that is not larger than life.